# How to manually find the file path for an android file?

Tags: java, android, file, ftp, io

In the code below I created a new text file. I am having trouble locating where this file is and I need the actual file path of this file so I can upload to a ftp server. Can someone please help me ?

Note: I am testing this app on an actual phone and I would like to physically find the file.

Thanks !

```
try
{
    final String testString = new String("Hello");
    FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("samplefile.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 

    osw.write(testString);
    osw.flush();
    osw.close();
}
catch(IOException ex)
{

}
```

Comment: This [tutorial about the File API](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html#overview) should help you.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** For what you have done, its in your current working directory.

**2.** For getting the path to the file use the `getFileStreamPath("samplefile.txt");`

The **SDK Doc** metions this:

**Returns the absolute path on the filesystem where a file created with openFileOutput(String, int) is stored.**

Answer (score 0):

It is usually under "data/data/package.name"